# IIS Output cache doesnt seem to cache static files

Tags: iis, cache, web.config

I have the configured caching below and Ive also used other scenarios but I cant get my JS files to show in the cache with the below commands.  So I dont think they are caching for my .js files.  Is there something else I need to do?

> netsh http show cache
>
> netsh http show cachestate

```
<caching>
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" varyByQueryString="*" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
```

My Failed Request Logging Has a ton of stuff but this looks interesting.  Not sure what it means.

```
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>HTTPSYS_CACHEABLE</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Cache</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Reason">IP_RESTRICTION_SET</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="CachePolicy">NO_CACHE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/walkthrough-iis-output-caching#caching-intricacies "Even if you enable Output Caching, IIS does not immediately cache a request. It must be requested a few times before IIS considers a request to be "cache worthy". "

Comment: I have JS files that get downloaded all the time, thousands of hits a day, so this threshold I can guaranee has been hit.

Comment: Then in the same article, it says "FREB tells you why something does not get cached" and you should analyze that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the staticfiles and its clientCache element within system.webServer to enable the cache headers for static files.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache for the details

Comment: I have and its already been there.  `<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />`